# Google chart download with custom filename and extension

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, download

I am using google chart and I want the user to download the chart as an image with one click of a button.

I have this code that downloads the chart but my problem is there is no extension and i cannot modify the filename. It only shows as "download" on my download list.

```
function getImgData(chartContainer) {
        var chartArea = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].parentNode;
        var svg = chartArea.innerHTML;
        var doc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
        var canvas = doc.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.setAttribute('width', chartArea.offsetWidth);
        canvas.setAttribute('height', chartArea.offsetHeight);

        canvas.setAttribute(
            'style',
            'position: absolute; ' +
            'top: ' + (-chartArea.offsetHeight * 2) + 'px;' +
            'left: ' + (-chartArea.offsetWidth * 2) + 'px;');
        doc.body.appendChild(canvas);
        canvg(canvas, svg);
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
        return imgData;
      }

      function saveAsImg(chartContainer) {
        var imgData = getImgData(chartContainer);

        // Replacing the mime-type will force the browser to trigger a download
        // rather than displaying the image in the browser window.
        window.location = imgData.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, most of the Visualization API charts now have a `getImageURI` method that will do all of the conversion to PNG format for you:

```
window.location = myChart.getImageURI();
```

Second, the file name is not something you can set in javascript.  In order to download the image with a specific file name, you have to send the image stream to your server, save it as a png file, and send the saved file back to the client as a download.

Comment: It seems like the downloading of chart as image is really not supported in Google Chart, I am following what you suggested right now but I'm having a new problem, I will post a new question.